# highcharts exporting - Java approach, maxWait property

Tags: java, highcharts

In the Java based export server for Highcharts there's a property called maxWait which ideally should be the max time an export request should wait before a phantomJs server becomes available in the pool.

However in the code I see that in BlockingQueuePool.java borrowObject() method

```
    T object = linkQueue.poll(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This is not honoring the maxWait property, shouldn't this be

```
    T object = linkQueue.poll(maxWait, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: You could be right. I have to check this.

Comment: Can you please check it and let me know? This significantly affects the error rate when multiple requests are sent to the server and the conversion takes a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. It's better to replace. It's logical to have control over how long you should wait to get a server object. This is also the expected behaviour when you read the comments in the app-convert.properties.

> When asking for a phantom server connection and nothing is available,
>   it waits for the number of milliseconds defined by maxWait

Change

```
T object = linkQueue.poll(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

to

```
T object = linkQueue.poll(maxWait, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I reported an issue [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2317) on GitHub.

Comment: Issue closed on Github by, [commit 7c81619](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/7c81619f9ca30ceb55069c097125f4812c7b0248)